# check if exists in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this model clas:

```
 public class usersInDashboard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string fbID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public int? countOfBid { get; set; }
}
```

and here's my controller
    ...

```
var participants = from q in db.firstWeekBids
                           where q.bidedItem == "laptop"
                           join w in db.Users
                               on q.userId equals w.Id
                           select new { q.bidCount };

        var model = new List<usersInDashboard>();

        foreach (var prt in participants)
        {
            var userDash = new usersInDashboard();
            userDash.fbID = user.id;
            if (model.Contains((userDash.fbID))
            {
               ...
            }
            else
            {
                userDash.fbID = user.id;
                userDash.firstName = user.name;
                userDash.countOfBid = prt.bidCount;
                model.Add(userDash);
            }
        }
return PartialView(model);
```

I need to check if this fbID exists in my list. user.id is string which is equal of fbID.
I've tried `if (model.Contains((userDash.fbID))` but it throws an exception

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(BlaBlaBla.Models.usersInDashboard)'
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\John\Documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\BlaBlaBla\BlaBlaBla\Controllers\AuctionController.cs    67  21

How can i do that?

Comment: That's because contains requires boolean argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using the default equality comparer, if you didn't create a custom one. If you want to know, whether any element of a sequence exists with the specified data, then use [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) overload with predicate instead of `Contains()`:

```
model.Any(x => x.fbID == userDash.fbID);
```

If you still want to use `Contains`, then either you can create your own comparer or your model should implement the [`System.IEquatable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx). Or try @teovankot answer.

But, as I said if you want to determine if any element in a collection matches a certain condition then you must use `Any()`.

Answer (score 3):

@Farhad way is a best i think, but if you still want to use `Contains` you can whrite like this:

```
model.Select(x => x.fbID).Contains(userDash.fbID)
```